# Регулярное выражение. Как оставить + при валидации?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите, как провести валидацию номера телефона при наборе в input, что была возможность оставлять знак плюса ? Приведу пример:

```js
$(".js-input-telephone").on('keyup', function() {
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\D/, '').substr(0, 13));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="RegisterForm_contact" class="bl_form__input js-input-telephone" type="tel" placeholder="Ваш E-mail" name="RegisterForm[contact]" value="+380">
```

При вводе не цифр оно их удаляет вместе с `+`. Мне необходимо, чтобы "+" сохранялся.

Comment: Наверное, `.replace(/[^\d+]/g,'').replace(/^([^+]*\+)|\++/g, '$1')`

Comment: `/(?=\+)|\D/g` - нашел такое решение, но не понял как работает))

Comment: Оба способа выше пропускают строку типа `+38012+24323`, где символ + находится в середине строки, хотя в условии вопроса не было сказано что только в начале строки. Возможно автору следует уточнить вопрос, для получения результата, который будет отвечать требованиям проверки номера.

Comment: @PotroNik `"+38012+24323".replace(/[^\d+]/g,'').replace(/^([^+]*\+)|\++/g, '$1')` => `+3801224323`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Вот fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s4om290n/1/ попробуйте удалить все символы из строки ввода, после написать любые цифры а после +/. Так получается скорее всего из за первой замены, [^\d+] в начале идут любые цифры и плюс без указания места плюса

Comment: @PotroNik И всё работает. Только один + разрешается.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, я об этом и писал в первом сообщении, что да, плюс один остается, но в середине, не правильно пример строки привел только, за что извиняюсь конечно.

Comment: @PotroNik В вопросе нет ни слова о том, что `+` должен быть оставлен только в начале строки. Даже примера нет. Если бы было, всё, что нужно поправить, это `.replace(/[^\d+]/g,'').replace(/^(\+)|\++/g, '$1')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPD2: Из за чего возникает проблема в вопросе автора:
В функции замены указан шаблон `\D` означающий любой символ отличный от цифр, символ + не относится к диапазону цифр и заменяется при вводе символа при переходе в функцию. Просто исключить замену символа `+` заменив `\D` на `[^\d+]`, тогда символ + можно будет записывать в строке в любом месте

---

Или как один из вариантов, это изменить регулярное выражение.

```js
(?:(^\+\d*)[^\d]|^[^\d+])
//изменен на
^(?:(\+?\d*)?[^\d]*)
//так как в случае если строка начинается не с плюс, можно ввести любой символ.
```

Захватывает в начале строки символ + и ноль и более цифр в группу, и заменяем любой символ отличный от цифры на пустоту, возвращая только значение захваченной группы `$1`
UPD: поправил проблему в случае если стереть строку, то можно было писать все что угодно

---

Пример:

```js
$(".js-input-telephone").on('keyup', function() {
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/^(?:(\+?\d*)?[^\d]*)/g, '$1').substr(0, 13));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="RegisterForm_contact" class="bl_form__input js-input-telephone" type="tel" placeholder="Номер телефона" name="RegisterForm[contact]" value="+380">
```

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего так:

```
$(this).val().replace(/^\D*(\+)|\D/g, '$1')
```

PS: Код из вопроса не делает того, что о нём написано.